# Merge and split records of two files

Tags: sas

I need a support with SAS:
suppose you have two sorted files:
File1 looks like this

```
        COD               Start         End
     employer1          01/01/2019    31/05/2019
     employer1          01/06/2019    31/12/2019
     employer2          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
     employer3          01/01/2019    31/10/2019
     employer3          01/11/2019    31/12/2019
     employer4          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
     employer5          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
     ........
     employer300       ...........    ...........
```

File2 looks like this:

```
        COD            hours_of_work     hours_of_vacancies   
     employer1          1.445,5               456,5   
     employer1          1.445,5               456,5
     employer2          3.876,88              6,8        
     employer3          4.987,23              32,65
     employer3          4.987,23              32,65
     employer4          838,38                  -
     employer5          543,9                   -
     ........
     employer300       ...........    ...........
```

I need to match the COD column of each file and when the employer* is doubled in the File1 because of the year-based split of the Start-End (i.e. two periods in the same year), divide the hours_of_work in the File2 corresponding to the same employer* by the mounts from the Start-End columns of File1:
For example: looking at the employer1, 1.445,5 will be divided by 5/12 because from 01/01/2019 and 31/05/2019 there are 5 mounts and by 7/12 because from 01/06/2019 to    31/12/2019 there are 7 mounts.

This need to be done not only for column hours_of_work but also for column hours_of_vacancies.

Can anyone help me please? I know that I have to do a merge but it is not clear how to do it exactly.

Thank you in advance

Expected output:
File3:

```
       COD            hours_of_work_out  hours_of_vacancies               
     employer1            3.469,2               -3.012,7             
     employer1            2.478                 -2.021,5     
     employer2           3.876,88               -3.870,08
     employer3           5.984,676              -5.952,026      
     employer3           29923,37               -29890,72
     employer4           838,38                   -
     employer5           543,9                    -
     ........
     employer300       ...........    ...........
```

Comment: Please show the expected output if those first few records were your input file.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? Divide by 5? It is 5 months and 7 months belong to the remaining? I would assume that would be divided by 5/12 and then 7/12 to allocate to proportion of the year?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit soon

Comment: Can we assume that if there are duplicates in File2 that each row will be identical for employer?

Comment: Yes exactly. The content is the same. They are duplicated only to mirror the split of the year of the same employer in File1

Comment: Why do you have two identical records in FILE2 for employer1 and employer3?  What does that mean?  Is each one half of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not sure how you're getting that data in the output but I suspect this is what you want to do.

```
data file1;
input       COD  : $10            Start   : ddmmyy10.      End : ddmmyy10. ;
format start end date9.;
cards;
 employer1          01/01/2019    31/05/2019
 employer1          01/06/2019    31/12/2019
 employer2          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
 employer3          01/01/2019    31/10/2019
 employer3          01/11/2019    31/12/2019
 employer4          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
 employer5          01/01/2019    31/12/2019
 ;;;;
 run;
 
 data file2;
 infile cards truncover;
input         COD  : $10           hours_of_work : commax.     hours_of_vacancies   : commax.;
cards;
 employer1          1.445,5               456,5   
 employer1          1.445,5               456,5
 employer2          3.876,88              6,8        
 employer3          4.987,23              32,65
 employer3          4.987,23              32,65
 employer4          838,38                  
 employer5          543,9                   
 ;;;;
run;

proc sort data=file2 nodupkey;
by cod;
run;

data want;
merge file1 file2;
by COD;
nMonths = intck('month', start, end)+1;

if not missing(hours_of_work) then  hours_of_work_adj = round(hours_of_work*nMonths/12, 0.01);
if not missing(hours_of_vacancies) then hours_of_vacancies_adj = round(hours_of_vacancies*nMonths/12, 0.01);


run;
```

Comment: Yes, with PROC IMPORT I first import the two tables that I sort for the column COD. Then I stop because not able. I'm trying with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the duplicate records in the second file.  Also you might need to add a YEAR variable to use in merging.

```
data dates;
  input cod :$20. (start end) (:yymmdd.);
  format start end yymmdd10.;
cards;
employer1 2019-01-01 2019-05-31
employer1 2019-06-01 2019-12-31
employer2 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
employer3 2019-01-01 2019-10-31
employer3 2019-11-01 2019-12-31
employer4 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
employer5 2019-01-01 2019-12-31
;

data hours;
  input cod :$20. work vacancies ;
cards;
employer1 1445.5  456.5
employer2 3876.88   6.8
employer3 4987.23  32.65
employer4  838.38  .
employer5  543.9   .
;
```

So if you want to prorate the hours by number of months in the dates record then it might be easiest to use INTCK() to count the months.

```
data want;
  merge dates hours;
  by cod;
  months = intck('month',start,end+1);
  work2 = work * (months/12);
  vacancies2 = vacancies * (months/12);
run;
```

Let's check the results:

```
proc print;
  by cod;
  id cod;
  sum work2 vacancies2;
run;
```

Output:

```
   cod          start         end    work   vacancies months    work2   vacancies2

employer1  2019-01-01  2019-05-31  1445.50    456.50     5      602.29    190.208
           2019-06-01  2019-12-31  1445.50    456.50     7      843.21    266.292
---------                                                     --------  ----------
employer1                                                      1445.50    456.500


employer2  2019-01-01  2019-12-31  3876.88      6.80    12     3876.88      6.800


employer3  2019-01-01  2019-10-31  4987.23     32.65    10     4156.03     27.208
           2019-11-01  2019-12-31  4987.23     32.65     2      831.21      5.442
---------                                                     --------  ----------
employer3                                                      4987.23     32.650


employer4  2019-01-01  2019-12-31   838.38       .      12      838.38       .


employer5  2019-01-01  2019-12-31   543.90       .      12      543.90       .
                                                              ========  ==========
                                                              11691.89    495.950
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! A nice solution too!

Comment: Missing a BY statement for the merge if you de-dup? If using original data would work as expected.

Comment: Added BY statement.